# Heroku failing to run node ES6 code

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have an express app generated with `express-generator` and have added in babel to transpile everything to a `bin` file.

I have also added in my `package.json`

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">= v8.9.0"
 }
```

to ensure it's running the same version of node as my local env.

For some reason, as soon as I added my service which is using es6 class syntax, the app fails to run:

```
export default class GifService {}
```

The only error I get in my logs are

> 2018-01-21T16:13:48.175448+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=gentle-depths-57675.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=a4c00cb7-5071-4883-a730-6355409d6aa2 fwd="86.28.187.108"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

which isn't much help.

I am also having the same issue when I use `async/await`. Any one come across this before?

Thanks

Comment: I should note that I have a procfile with the following `web: node bin/app.js` which is telling heroku to run my app from the bin / transpiled file

Comment: It's hard to tell based on such a thin info about your project... Are you aware that Heroku will not install your devDependencies by default? In order to force that you need to set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false in the ENV vars.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I am actually running the build locally and all runs locally from `bin/app.js`. I then deploy the whole project to heroku and as mentioned my procfile specifies to run from `bin/app.js`

Comment: Well definitely there is a difference when deploying to heroku compared to your local setup. I would try to place logs in the server code and ssh to the dyno, see if that gives more clues: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1112

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma those differences are what I am trying to get to the bottom of. I am running the exact same transpiled code in the same node version. What else can be different? As for logs, I have done this. I have stripped back the code to the basics. It is only when I put in es6 class or async / await syntax in is when it breaks and shows the error I posted in the original post.

Comment: Here is one of my project, this deploys fine on heroku and backend code contains ES6, class and async/await. Maybe it will help you: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-react-boiler.nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue with my babel presets.

I was trying to transpile to stage-2 with a bunch of plugins

old .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "syntax-async-functions",
    "transform-regenerator"
  ]
}
```

I'm guessing this isn't supported by Heroku.

I have since changed my babel preset to the following:

new .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```